# How to iterate through a pattern and display the results in a colum

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column with a pattern (e.g Red, Blue, Green) that I want to repeat automatically in another column.

E.g.

A

1 Red
2 Blue
3 Green
4 Red
5 Blue
6 Green

I need to use a formula as I have a condition that i need to meet with an if.

It must be very simple but I am stuck!

Comment: Welcome. Your scenario isn't quite clear. You said that you have a column with a pattern (e.g Red, Blue, Green), but it is not clear what this `1 Red 2 Blue 3 Green 4 Red 5 Blue 6 Green` means. It is the contents of a single cell, or row by column? Are the numbers part of the data or do they indicate rows? I suggest you add two screenshots, one with the existing pattern, and the other showing the pattern that you are trying to achieve.